# Why should operand contain only one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This is a valid query:

```
select
(select 1),
(select 2),
(select 3);
```

However, this is not:

```
select
(select 1),
(select 2, 3);
```

From DB logics' perspective, why is second query not allowed?

Is there a fix to the second query to make it legal and return same (or similar) result as in the first query, given that query result will be guaranteed to contain only one row?

To clarify:

1,2 and 3 are placeholders for real queries which take many seconds to run. 2 and 3 come from same table, if I break them apart, the query will take twice as long to run. I would like to avoid this overhead, if possible.

Comment: @MostyMostacho thank you, 123 are placeholders for very complicated real queries, I would like to avoid additional overhead of duplicating a query N times.

Comment: If the queries are slow, consider posting them here for help in optimizing them. We could only guess at what their contents might be.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I appreciate that. I am looking for a generic solution.

Comment: I agree with Michael. Or at least post the output you're expecting to get to better understand what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard telling without knowing the real use-case, but you can usually do it with a join:

```
SELECT t1.f1, t2.f2, t2.f3 FROM
(SELECT 1 AS f1) AS t1,
(SELECT 2 AS f2, 3 AS f3) AS t2
```

http://sqlize.com/9l0h8pcZKJ

Comment: that's perfect. there's a small typo in `t3.f3`.

Comment: Fixed. I can't believe I made that mistake and didn't notice it doesn't work in SQLize...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that subqueries as columns must be single valued.

Instead, select the individual columns from the subquery as a table:

```
select
(select 1),
2, 3
from (select 2, 3) t;
```